# Most optimal way of working with ExecutorService in static method that is called very often?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, executorservice

I'm having some time-bound method that is getting called quite often on the server running 24/7 in a concurrent environment.

I'm considering some ways of optimising this.

Case 1: no optimisation, just create ExecutorService on every method call and then shut it down:

```
public static boolean doSomeWork(@Nonnull String input) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<Boolean> future = executorService.submit(() -> checkSmth(input));
    try {
        return future.get(Constants.TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
        future.cancel(true);
        return false;
    } finally {
        shutdownExecutorGracefully(executorService);
    }
}

private static void shutdownExecutorGracefully(ExecutorService executorService) {
    executorService.shutdown();
    try {
        if (!executorService.awaitTermination(Constants.EXECUTOR_SERVICE_SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            executorService.shutdownNow();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        executorService.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

Case 2: make it a static field and never call `shutdown`:

```
private static final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public static boolean doSomeWork(@Nonnull String input) {
    Future<Boolean> future = executorService.submit(() -> checkSmth(input));
    try {
        return future.get(Constants.TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
        future.cancel(true);
        return false;
    }
}
```

What way would be the most optimal from performance, GC and correctness perspectives?

Comment: You may get your answer if you elaborate on what you want to achieve with the first approach in comparison with the second one. What do you believe to get from a fresh `ExecutorService` that you won't get from an already used one? Although you have to consider the uptime for your program: is it a server that is intended to run 24/7, or is it a one shot program (that may still run hours before it reaches it terminates as intended).

Comment: there isn't a single answer to the question.  it all depends what you are looking for.  one solution may be more performant in some situations than the other.  one may use too many resources in some situations.  but it all depends on what your specific requirements are.

Comment: thanks, I clarfied that this is a server running 24/7

Comment: This `shutdownExecutorGracefully` after every job subverts the entire timeout goal. When the job doesn’t respond to interruption, you are always waiting `TIMEOUT_MILLIS` *plus* `EXECUTOR_SERVICE_SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT_MILLIS`, just for the sake of calling `shutdownNow()` which will have no effect in this scenario, as a job not responding to interruption when calling `cancel(true)` will not respond interruption when calling `shutdownNow()` either.

Answer (score 1):

Those two code fragments have vastly different performance characteristics:

The first fragment creates a single-thread threadpool for every invocation. If several threads call `doSomeWork()` concurrently each will have its threadpool and the `checkSmth(input)` will execute in parallel.

The second fragment uses a single-thread threadpool for all invocations. If multiple threads call `doSomework()` concurrently there will be only one thread for executing `checkSmth(input)` - the work is sequentialized and you will see more timeouts occuring (because the timeout for `future.get(Constants.TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` starts when you call `future.get()`, not when the task of the threadpool starts the work.)

The first fragment will create many short-lived threads and that was one of the reasons to introduce threadpools to Java: to avoid the creation of many short-lived threads.

IMHO the better solution is to create only one threadpool (like in your second fragment), but (depending on your requirements) to create a threadpool with multiple threads.